# How do I change the value of a variable on top of the same existing variable -- multiple times? (Java)

Tags: java, variables, calculator

So, I challenged myself to create a simple calculator having incorporated a user input system.

The first bit of code (shown below) asks the user what their number is and stores it in a **double** called **"num."**

The program then asks the user what they want to do (Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide, or show the answer) and I put this in a **while loop,** because I'm thinking that they might want to work with more than 2 numbers. If the user wants the answer, then they'll choose that and the while loop will stop.

**My problem is, I want the program to be able to take the number and add, subtract, etc., it with the existing number from before. Essentially, I want the value of the variable to change repeatedly, but I just don't know how to do that.**

For example, if the user starts out with the number 2, and adds 2, then multiplies it by 4, the answer should then be 16. I just can't get my code to do that.

I realize that my code is wrong, considering I've tested it, but I just can't wrap my head around what it is I need to do. I feel as though I'm close, but anything can go as I'm still sort of new to Java.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

I think this link could take you to the site to edit it and what not: https://repl.it/@ANGELRAMIREZ6/Basic-Calculator

Here's my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner userWhatWillDo = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner userNum = new Scanner(System.in);

    double num, answer;
    int what, numOfNums, keepGoing = 1;

    while (keepGoing == 1) {

       System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
       num = userNum.nextDouble();

       System.out.println("1=Add; 2=Subtract; 3=Multiply; 4=Divide; 5=Answer");
       what = userWhatWillDo.nextInt();

       switch(what) {
         case 1:
            num += num;
            break;

        case 2:
            num -= num;
            break;

        case 3:
            num *= num;

        case 4:
            num /= num;
      }

      if(what == 5) {
        keepGoing = 2;
        System.out.println(answer);
      }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Your switch is missing break statements.

Comment: First: do not create to `Scanner`s for the same input stream - this will lead to problems if users enter multiple values on the same line. Second: after entering the operation the user needs a way to input the second value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- use println instead of print to flush output, or flush manually
- you only need 1 scanner
- init `answer` to 0
- lines in your switch should alter `answer`

```
      case 1:
      answer += num;
      break;
```

- use `break` in each `case`

Also:

- check for `divide by 0`
- catch invalid input errors

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

double num, answer=0;
int what, numOfNums, keepGoing = 1;

while (keepGoing == 1) {

    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    num = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("1=Add; 2=Subtract; 3=Multiply; 4=Divide; 5=Answer");
    what = sc.nextInt();

    switch(what) {
      case 1:
      answer += num;
      break;

      case 2:
      answer -= num;
      break;

      case 3:
      answer *= num;
      break;

      case 4:
      answer /= num;
      break
    }

    if(what == 5) {
      keepGoing = 2;
      System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

To fix your calculation logic:

- Ask for number and assign to `answer`
- Start your loop asking for operation, then number.

Comment: I took care of the extra Scanners, fixed my mistake of altering the num variable instead of the answer variable, and added breaks after each case, and the program can run, but the calculations seem to be all messed up. When I inputted 4 and divided it by 2 (essentially 4/2), the program gave me 0.0 for my answer. One thing I did notice, however, is that when I attempted to do 5+5+5+5, the answer was always 5 less than the value it was supposed to give. For example, 5+5+5+5 = 15 instead of 20. I'm thinking this has something to do with the way the values are stored and then used?

Comment: You get the wrong answer because your operation applies to the preceding value.  You ignore the last value when exiting.  You need to ask for the number, set answer to it, and then start the loop, asking for the operation first.

Comment: > When I inputted 4 and divided it by 2. You are doing 0/4, and then ignoring the 2.

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you! The code itself wasn't hard at all, but it was wrapping my head around what values would get assigned to which variables! I did just that; fixed my code under your corrections, ran my code, but the only thing was, the while loop would run through my code once more in the end after I had ended the loop (setting keepGoing = 2) and it would have me input another number that didn't do anything at all, but afterwards, it'd give me the correct answer to any calculation. All there was left to do was fix that with a simple do...while loop. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone that contributed and helped tweak my code, I managed to get my very first calculator working! It's very basic and could really use a lot of work; so much work, but the basics are pretty much done! It's essentially a working calculator! Though, it can only do addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. It can't do much more than that. If anyone wants to see what I now have, I will post the link to the code so you can run it if you'd like. Again, thank you all.

Link: https://repl.it/@ANGELRAMIREZ6/Basic-Calculator-1Fixed

**(How I fixed my code - EXPLANATIONS)** -- Okay, so looking back to my first piece of code, I did have unnecessary scanners that I ended taking out (cheers to Thomas Kläger and Steven Spungin).

After doing that, I then fixed how the calculations were done. Initially, I couldn't wrap my head around how they were supposed to work, so I very clumsily made them all relate to this same piece of code: **num += num**, which was essentially **num = num + num** (props to  tshimkus, Daniel Rivero Capellan and Steven Spungin that opened my eyes to this silly mistake. I changed it to **answer += num**, which makes a lot more sense.

After fixing the calculations, I thought my code would work, but I came to a stop, as the calculations I was getting were completely random and not correct at all. Or, rather, the program was doing the correct thing in doing what I had wrongly coded it to do. Special thanks to Steven Spungin who set it all in stone and helped my understand that the problem lied within the way my values were being stored.

Before a **loop** would continuously ask what numbers would want to be used and what was going to be done to them (add, subtract, etc.), I prompted the user with what number they wanted to start out with and set that value to **answer,** and then I ran the **loop.** In this loop, any number inputted by the same prompt, **Enter a number**, would be stored into the **num** variable and would ultimately be added, subtracted, multiplied, or divided to the initial number, whose value was **answer.** And logically/mathematically, that makes sense, considering the first value would be **answer,** and the numbers after would be **num,** and it makes sense when you look at this code: **answer += num**.

All in all, it was a simple program with a bit of a tricky execution to start it off (at least for me). I recommend this little project for anyone who's a beginner in coding in Java. The program is far from finished and I'm sure the code could be executed much more efficiently, but I'll go ahead and take my char = W; for this one. (I even added a "divide by zero" error. Go ahead and try it yourself!)

**BIG THANKS TO EVERYONE WHO HELPED!**

In case the link doesn't work, here's my working code:

import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

double num = 0, answer=0;
  int what, keepGoing = 1, keepAsking = 1;

System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
      answer = sc.nextDouble();

while (keepGoing == 1) {

```
  System.out.println("1=Add; 2=Subtract; 3=Multiply; 4=Divide; 5=Answer");
  what = sc.nextInt();

  if (what != 5) {
      do {
      System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
      num = sc.nextDouble();
      keepAsking = 2;
    }
  while (keepAsking == 1);
  }

  switch(what) {
    case 1:
    answer += num;
    break;

    case 2:
    answer -= num;
    break;

    case 3:
    answer *= num;
    break;

    case 4:
    answer /= num;
    break;
  }

  if (what == 4 && answer == 0) {
    System.out.println("ERROR. Cannot divide by zero. Try again.");
    keepGoing = 2;
  }

    if(what == 5) {
    keepGoing = 2;
    keepAsking = 2;
    System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Appart other users have noticed. Wrong switch case statement and multiple readers in the same stream. I suggest the following.

You have to initialize variable answer before using it. for example to 0.

`Second num+=num` means `num = num + num` and what you want is accumulate the operation results in answer like, `answer = answer+num`. That can be achieved with `answer+=num`.

With this changes your calculator should work properly.

Comment: I took care of the extra Scanners, fixed my mistake of altering the num variable instead of the answer variable, and added breaks after each case, and the program can run, but the calculations seem to be all messed up. When I inputted 4 and divided it by 2 (essentially 4/2), the program gave me 0.0 for my answer. One thing I did notice, however, is that when I attempted to do 5+5+5+5, the answer was always 5 less than the value it was supposed to give. For example, 5+5+5+5 = 15 instead of 20. I'm thinking this has something to do with the way the values are stored and then used?